# XLIFF2 Editor For Ubuntu?

Tags: translation

Is there any tool on the web, or that runs on Ubuntu that can provides an interface to edit [XLIFF2](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/xliff/XLIFF2.0). I can't find anything.

I've got localization files I'm producing Angular 4 and I'd like to give them to a translator with a tool to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a website http://xliff.brightec.co.uk/ which can help you in that. There are other option on web as well but I used this one usually because its easy and straight forward.

Comment: This website is taking full access to your twitter account. I dont think it s a good idea to use it ;)